# ES6 Classes: Get the proper name of a subclass in a super method

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6, subclass

Suppose I have the following:

```
class ThingWithWheels {
    constructor( numWheels ) {
        this.numWheels = numWheels
    }
    toString() {
        return this.constructor.name;
    }
}
class Car extends ThingWithWheels {
    constructor( color ) {
        super(4);
        this.color = color;
    }
    toString() {
        return `${this.color} ${super.toString()}`;
    }
}
```

This is pretty standard Object Oriented Programming. However, in NodeJS v5.6.0 if I make a red car, and call `toString()` it will give `Red ThingWithWheels`, not `Red Car`. When I call the super method, it treats the `this` as a `ThingWithWheels` not a `Car`.

1. Why is this?
2. Is there a way to do this where the super method gets the name right?

Comment: Which of these inherits from the other here?  You don't show any inheritance.

Comment: you mean class Car extends ThingWithWheels, read here, you have to do some more research: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: I forgot to type the "extends ThingWithWheels". Doesn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this in node.js 5.10.1, and it gave me "Red Car", so it might have been a bug in 5.6.

Comment: Turns out you get the wrong name when you accidentally make an instance of the super class instead of the subclass.

*shame intensifies*